# If you condition on O, you stop the flow of information from which arrow into or out of O?

Tags: confounding, dag, backdoor-path, collider

[image]

Why does conditioning on O open up this second channel below?[image]

Comment: Is your question about the intuition of conditioning on colliders, or purely about the mechanics of d-separation/causal DAGs? The linked answer is helpful for the latter.